# Is it possible to consume a Vue.js app as a microfronted in a React.js app?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I have a basic Vue.js app and I want to consume it in a React.js app as a react component, is it possible to achieve via module federation? if yes how? please tell me how do I expose the vue.js app in its webpack.config.js and how do I consume in the react app?

I have tried exposing the index.js file of the vue.js app and then tried consuming the remoteEntry.js file in the react app through module federation, it did not work. Maybe i am not doing it properly.

Comment: I don't think it would be very simple as you would need to preserve state across rerenders if you load it yourself. Have you looked at a library like https://github.com/devilwjp/veaury

Comment: @Djave Hi, I will check this library out, thanks